# WPF - Page navigation

Tags: wpf, navigation

I am creating a WPF Application in VS 2012. 
My MainWindow acts as a header/footer wrapper for the pages that are navigated to.
Within my footer I have added custom back/forward buttons, but I want their visibility to change based off of the CanGoBack and CanGoForward properties.

I can create C#  routines that will hide/show the buttons but the function only runs once at initialization. I need these functions to fire off every time a new page is loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is is a simple example where I use Grids as Pages and i use a Grid array to save the instances of the grids. I hope this would help in your scenario.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PageNavigation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Name="page1" Background="Beige">
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Page1</Label>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="page2" Background="Blue" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Page2</Label>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="page3" Background="Green" Visibility="Hidden" >
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Page3</Label>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="page4" Background="Cyan" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"   HorizontalAlignment="Center">Page4</Label>
        </Grid>
        <Button Name="btn_Next" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Next" Click="btn_Next_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btn_Previous" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Previous" Click="btn_Previous_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Grid[] pages;
        int activePage = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            pages = new Grid[4];
            pages[0] = this.page1;
            pages[1] = this.page2;
            pages[2] = this.page3;
            pages[3] = this.page4;
        }
        void Next() {
            if (activePage<pages.Length-1)
            {
                pages[activePage].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                activePage++;
                pages[activePage].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }    
        }
        void Previous()
        {
            if (activePage > 0)
            {
                pages[activePage].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                activePage--;
                pages[activePage].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void btn_Previous_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Previous();
        }

        private void btn_Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Next();
        }
    }
```